# Hive - How to know which execution engine I am currently using

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hive, tez

> I want to automate my hive ETL workflow in such a way
>   that I need to execute hive jobs on the basis of execution engine (Tez
>   or MR) because of memory constraints.

Would you please help, as I wanted to cross-check in-between of my whole work-flow which execution engine currently I'm dealing with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Hive execution engine is controlled by `hive.execution.engine` property. It can be either of the following:

- `mr` (Map Reduce, default)
- `tez` (Tez execution, for Hadoop 2 only)
- `spark` (Spark execution, for Hive 1.1.0 onward).

The property can be read & updated using hive/beeline cli

- For reading - `SET hive.execution.engine;`
- For updating - `SET hive.execution.engine=tez;`

If you want to programmatically get this value out, you must go for HiveClient which supports multiple ways like JDBC, Java, Python, PHP, Ruby, C++, etc.

References

- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=82903061#ConfigurationProperties-hive.execution.engine
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveClient